# socket.IO two clients

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

I've got two clients and one server.

Client 1:

```
const socket = io("http://localhost:4000");
socket.emit('newMessage',msg);
```

Server:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('newMessage', (msg) => {
        socket.emit("newMessageForward",msg); //forwarding 
    });
});
```

Client 2:

```
const socket = io("http://localhost:4000");
socket.on("newMessageForward", (msg) => { // THERE'S THE PROBLEM HERE 
        console.log("Yes"); //NEVER EXECUTED
});
```

As you can see I'm simply trying to forward msg from `Client 1` to `Client 2` using server. Server is listening `newMessage` and forward. But forward message is never received in `Client 2`  code. Please, help.

Comment: UPD:
Just found the solution with ```emit.broadcast```.

Comment: docco here https://socket.io/docs/v4/broadcasting-events/#to-all-connected-clients-except-the-sender